# need to call this Task.php file from UserController.php file

Tags: php

I need to execute this Task.php file once the iteration gets completed, as this Task.php has some huge task to do i cannot do it sequentially.
once coming out of the loop i need to trigger this Task.php so that it will take care of post process and my main method doesn't have to wait for its response.
I am new to php and laravel please give some solution for this.
I need to make it work for both Windows and Linux

```
$file_to_execute='C:/xampp/htdocs/liveLogger/test/app/Http/Controllers/Task.php';
$php_exe_location='C:/xampp/php/php.exe';

exec($php_exe_location, $file_to_execute);
```

Comment: did you read this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling ...using `exec()` to call to PHP is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

You need a queue to run long processes. exec() is not an async solution and you spend more time to parse the response or on error handling part etc.

Gearman Job Server is well integrated solution for PHP and you might use other languages as worker or client or vice versa.

Please check these examples from php.net

https://www.php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse-task.php